# Why decltype is required in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

I am learning `decltype` in C++ 11.

The function of `auto` and `decltype` seems duplicated and I don't understand why we need `decltype`.

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype), Its primary intended use is in generic programming, where it is often difficult, or even impossible, to express types that depend on template parameters.

In generic programming, I can use `auto` when it is difficult to express types:

```
template <typename T>
void MakeAnObject (const T& builder)
{
    auto val = builder.MakeObject();
    // do stuff with val
}
```

I don't understand why `decltype` is required.

Can `decltype` do something which `auto` can not?

Comment: `decltype` is quite useful for, say, `auto add(T a, T b) -> decltype(a+b)`.

Comment: And what when you don't want a _variable_, only a _type_?

Comment: 'Do stuff with val' could be: `std::vector<decltype(val)> v; /*...*/`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369131/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`auto` means "the variable's type is deduced from the initialiser."

`decltype` refers to a type in an arbitrary context.

Here's an example where you can't use `auto`:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
void madd(const T &t, const U &u, const V &v, decltype(t * u + v) &res)
{
  res = t * u + v;
}
```

There is no initialiser in the parameter declaration (and there can't be), so you can't use `auto` there.

The thing is, 99% of uses for `decltype` is in templates. There's no equivalent functionality for it there. In non-template code, `auto` is usually what you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

While it is useful to get variables declared using `auto`, if you actually need to know the type of an expression, e.g., when producing a return type for a templatized function, `auto` isn't sufficient: you need to not just name a value but you need to get hold of type, e.g., to modify it. If anything could be dropped it would be `auto`. However, the use of `decltype()` tends to be a lot more wordy, i.e., `auto` is a nice short-cut.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` is deduction of a type from an initializer.

Example:

```
auto x = 7; 
auto x = expression;
```

`decltype[E]` is the type ("declared type") of the name or expression E and can be used in declarations.

Example:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto mult(T& t1, U& u1) -> decltype (t1 * u1)
{
    return t1 * u1;
}
```

Even the second case of auto can be replace by decltype but auto looks good for this.

```
decltype (j * i) m = j * i;
```

decltype is mostly used in template programming.