# When should I use decltype(x) instead of auto to declare the type of a variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

I see `decltype(x)` used inside macros where `x` is a variable name because the type of the object isn't known inside macros.

For example:

```
decltype(x) y = expr;
```

I could just have easily use `auto` instead of `decltype`. So what are those situations where `decltype` is needed for a variable type declaration instead of `auto`?

Comment: `decltype(x) y = expr;` is not the same as `auto y = expr;` - there could very likely be an implicit conversion of some form in the former, but not in the latter.

Comment: `auto` is for normal people and every-day use. `decltype` is for generic library code that you should almost never see in normal life.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: are you talking as a library implementer or as a user? I sure hope users don't see `decltype` regularly.

Comment: I mean most people who use C++ for a living. I expect only a very small part of those (namely library implementers) to use `decltype` a lot, and only another small fraction to use it occasionally, and a large proportion to never see it. If your shop has a good core library team, hopefully they'll shield you from this :-) And if you're organizing your own codebase by yourself, I'd still hope that the bits that use `decltype` are kept in a corner away from most of the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the difference between decltype and auto as a placeholder type for variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12084040)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use it when the required type of `y` is:

- different (or potentially different) from the type of `expr`. If it was the same then `auto` would be more concise.
- similarly for `auto &` or other modifications of the type of `expr` that `auto` can express.

and one of the following:

- dependent on something in the surrounding code (i.e. not always the same type) and difficult to write using type traits or similar. This will tend to happen in template code. There might be a type trait that you can use to get the required type from the template parameters, but then again there might not so a use of `decltype` would save you defining one.
- always the same type, (or dependent on template parameters in a way that is easy to express using existing type traits or similar) but the type is very long-winded to write and there is a much shorter and clear expression you can use instead.

So for example replacing `std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type` with `decltype(*it)` might well be a win, although `auto` does often handle such cases.

Subjective judgements enter at the point of "what is difficult", "what is long-winded" and "what is clear", but the rules of procedure can be the same regardless of how you make those judgements in specific cases.

Comment: But in the case ``decltype(x) y = expr;`` where ``y`` and ``expr`` are not of the same type, wouldn't it be easier to write ``auto y = x(expr);``? Or does this simply reflect personal preference, and whether you'd want explicit conversions to occur?

Comment: @DiederickC.Niehorster: if `x` is the type, then you'd just write `x y = expr;` (or `x y{expr};`), not either of those two things. I think the question presumes that `x` is not already a type. If `x` is not a type then `x(expr)` probably doesn't work. And if it is a type it's a "scary" C-style cast, it might do a `const_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` or both depending on what type `x` ends up being. Better use `static_cast`.

Answer (score 26):

`decltype` becomes handy when you need to return some unknown type, which is evaluated during compilation:

```
template<class A, class B>
void MultiplyAB(A a, B b, decltype(a*b)& output)
{
    output = a * b;
}
```

Additionally, if you don't like the way the output is handled by a reference, then you can also use the late-specified return type (and also use the `decltype`):

```
template<class A, class B>
auto MultiplyAB(A a, B b) -> decltype(a*b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

All of this, and more, is described by B. Stroustrup in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#suffix-return).

Comment: TBH the latter isn't defining the type of a variable, it defines a return type.

Answer (score 18):

When you want `y` to always have whatever the declared type of `x` is.

Comment: But I will still know the type of `x` so I could just replace `decltype(x)` with `[typeOfX] y = expr`.

Comment: That's making `y` always have that specific type. Not the same.

Comment: @templateboy do you know the return type of `foo(a+b/c)` always?

Comment: @templateboy - expr could be a function or an overloaded operator or anything

Comment: @templateboy what if you changed the type of x later? Then you'd need to go through and find everywhere that you assumed you the correct type and hardcoded it. decltype(x) allows you to encode that type relationship so if you do change x's type at some point in the future, you don't have to do some massive text substitution or figure out everywhere you declared something else whose type depends on the type of x.

Answer (score 16):

In the context of your question,

- You should use `decltype` when you want a new variable with **precisely the same type** as the original variable.
- You should use `auto` when you want to **assign** the value of some expression to a new variable and you want or need its type to be deduced.

`decltype(x) y` always declares `y` with precisely the same type as the type `x` was declared with. In particular:

- If `x` has type `const int` then `y` will have type `const int`.
- If `x` has type `int[100]` then `y` will have type `int[100]`.
- If `x` has type `int f(int)` then `y` will have type `int f(int)`. Yes, this actually declares another *function* with the same type as the original.
- If `x` has type `int&` then `y` will have type `int&`; and if `x` has type `int&&` then `y` will have type `int&&`.

`auto y = x` will declare `y` with the following types, when `x` has the following types:

- If `x` has type `const int`, then `y` will have type `int`. That is, `auto` **strips top-level cv-qualifiers.**
- If `x` has type `int[100]`, then `y` will have type `int*`. That is, `auto` **performs array to pointer conversion**. [1]
- If `x` has type `int f(int)`, then `y` will have type `int (*)(int)`. That is, `auto` **performs function to function pointer conversion**. [2]
- Finally, if `x` has type `int&` or `int&&`, then `y` will have type `int`. That is, `auto` **removes references**.

[1] You can't use `decltype` here because you can't copy-initialize an array.

[2] You can't use `decltype` here because you can't initialize a function.

[3] The reason why `auto` strips references is that C++ has no expressions of reference type! Once initialized, the "reference ness" of a reference becomes invisible.

Note that `decltype` also does something entirely different when its argument is not an id-expression, which I won't get into here.

Comment: I think if `x` is declared as `int&&` it is still an lvalue, just it it is allowed to bind to an rvalue.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever your variable type isn't related to the expression being evaluated.

E.g:

```
struct Bar
{
    Bar(int) {} // implicitly constructable
}

struct Bar2
{
    Bar2(int) {} // implicitly constructable
}

struct Foo
{
    static Bar var;
}

struct Foo2
{
    static Bar2 var;
}

template <typename T>
void dummy()
{
    decltype(T::var) myVar = 42;
}

dummy<Foo>(); // myVar is of type Bar1
dummy<Foo2>(); // myVar is of type Bar2
auto myAutoVar = 42; // type is int
```

Of course this is just one use case, there are many more out there.

Answer (score 7):

`decltype` is significantly more versatile that `auto` and can always be used in place of it. Therefore I think it's pretty safe to say that `decltype` should only be used in cases where it's completely necessary, so if `auto` produces the wrong result you should use decltype. Also you can't as of yet use `auto` in return types and parameters, so you can use `decltype` there as well. C++14 will significantly increase the potential uses of `auto` and I would guess c++17 will go further. So the situations to use `decltype` will only be when you need to change the resulting type of `expr`

Another thing to consider is that `decltype` isn't really necessary unless you're writing library code, auto is nice for everyday programming if you want to make your code more concise, it's up for debate wether using as much `auto` as possible is good, but it's virtually necessary when working with unutterable types like lambdas.